# Sed doubts when n occurrences are used

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I'm trying to replace the *n<sup>th</sup>* occurrence of a substring in a file. I tried to achieve this using [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) but all attempts failed to give me the desired output. Some of the attempts are:

```
sed 's/old/new/g'
sed 's/old/new/3'
sed 's/old/new/3g'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. Please [edit] your question and include extra information such as the command you used to lead to the statement you made. This will help others to see the issues so that they can help you. To edit, click your post's [edit] link located a line below and to the left of the question, then paste in the requested material. Also, have a look at [ask].

Comment: Am I correct to understand that you want to replace the _nth_ occurrence of substring _old_ by _new_. Or do you want to replace the first _n_ occurrences? And from your edits, I understand you tried `sed 's/old/new/g'` and `sed 's/old/new/3g'`. Also, why do you say that `sed "s/old/new/1"` does not perform any substitutions?

Comment: I have updated your question. Can you check if this reflects what you want?

Comment: So i have three lines..In all these lines I have the word "test" but i want to replace it only in second line and third line. So i used the commands "s/old/new/2" and "s/old/new/3" . But the content does not get replaced. Is this the right way or do i have a different way to approach this?

Comment: Yes the updated question is correct

Comment: `sed "2,3s/old/new/"` will replace the first occurrence of substring "old" by string "new" in lines 2 till 3. You are asking to replace the second and third occurrence in every line, but if there is only one string "old", nothing will happen.

Comment: So i have a requirement where the lines count may change, it may become 4rth and fifth lines..is there any command similar to the old one(sed "s/old/new/1").where i can check for the occurences for the entire file instead of the line

Comment: Ill add the exact scenario here [Line 1 : test is what][Line 2: test is why][Line 3: test is nill] So these may move to the next line and so on.So i want to replace the value test in line 2 and line 3 alone . But the line count may vary .It may become line 4 and line 5 . But the above command replaces it only within a particular line and not with respect to the entire file. So i want to replace the second and third time its coming in a different line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most common usage of [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) is to perform a replacement such as

```
sed 's/foo/bar/' file
```

This will replace the first occurrence of the string `foo` by the string `bar` and it will do this for every line in `file`.

If you want to replace the 3rd occurrence of the string `foo` only, but do this for every line, then you can write:

```
sed 's/foo/bar/3' file.
```

Finally, if you want to replace all occurrences, then you use :

```
sed 's/foo/bar/g' file.
```

Any combination such as

```
sed 's/foo/bar/3g' file
```

results in **unspecified behaviour**.

If you want to replace the *n<sup>th</sup>* occurrence in a file than [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) is not the right tool, but [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) or [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) might be better.

- If you know you have *maximum* one occurrence of "foo" per line, you can do

  ```
  awk '/foo/{c++}(c==n){sub("foo","bar")}1' file
  ```
- If more than a single occurrence per line might appear it becomes a bit more tricky, various solutions are possible:

  ```
  awk 'BEGIN{FS="foo";OFS="bar";n=5}
       (c<n) && (c+NF-1>=n) {
          for(i=1;i<NF;++i) printf $i ((++c==n) ? OFS : FS); print $NF; next
       }
       {c+=NF-1; print}' file
  ```

Comment: Ill give the example i need solution for . I have the following lines - line 1 - "test"  line 2 -"test" and if i use the above command it does not work whereas it works with /g.And im using this inside a shell script..Should i do anything different?

Comment: so basically /3 searches for third occurence in a line, instead i want it like the third occurence in a file

Comment: @Ragavendarbalaji I have updated the answer to accomodate your request

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the error in this command : awk -v n=2 '/\'text\' =>.*/^C{ if (++count == n) sub(/\'text\' =>.*/, "\'text\' => \'my-text\',"); } 1' filename.php

Comment: @Ragavendarbalaji I don't know what this command should do, but the `^C` looks a bit dodgy

Comment: Ill be more clear - This works - awk '/test/{c++}(c==2){sub("test","testcheck")}1' test.php  but i want to do it for a text containing single quotes for eg - 'test'. So i tried this awk "/'test' =>.*/{c++}(c==2){sub("'test' =>.*","'test' => 'testcheck',")}1" test.php . But this doesnt work @kvantour

Comment: Hi @kvantour any suggestions on how to execute the above command for text with single quotes?

Comment: Single quotes in a single quoted program block are typed as `'"'"'` which closes the single quoted block, prints the single quote in-between double quotes and reopens the single quoted program block. More here https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Quoting.html

Comment: Hi @kvantour thank you so much .. it worked.how do i change awk so that i use it inside a script. i dont want temperory changes to be displayed instead i want the changes to be made in the file..like sed -i

Comment: @Ragavendarbalaji Sorry but this is not how Stack Overflow works. We are not a coding service and you will have to learn the languages Bash, Awk, and Sed. The user manuals of these tools are incredibly detailed and there is enough information on the internet about them. The last two questions (unrelated to your original post) have been asked multiple times on SO and the answers are here (or search _awk and inplace_ with google).